# xxx does not appear to be an hg repository after push finishes

Tags: mercurial

Just several days ago, when I push to a hg repository, something like 'xxx does not appear to be an hg repository' appears after push finishes. The output looks like this:

```
pushing to http://xxx/scm/hg/jewelry
searching for changes    
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
abort: 'http://xxx/scm/hg/jewelry' does not appear to be an hg repository:
---%<--- (no content-type)

---%<---
!
```

The push is actually finished, so this can't be a big deal, except that it's really annoying.
So did anyone come across this?

BTW, the hg version on client side is 2.1 & server is 2.3. But this does not seem to be a version problem because it just came out from nowhere several days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain but it looks like someone has installed a hook on the server to run something after the push and their hook is broken?  Do you see any extra detail if you add `--debug` to the push?  Any chance someone recently added a server side changegroup hook?  Perhaps 'notify' to send out emails?

Comment: Well, it seems that some version of hg would use a command named pushkey after push finishes. However, the scm manager on the server side is now newly enough to recognize that command and returns a "Method Not Allowed" error. So I upgraded the scm manager, then problem solved. Thanks for the tip.
But I don't recall updating hg recently, so still don't know how this came suddenly.

Comment: Did you start using bookmarks recently?  If you're trying to push bookmarks that goes as a pushkey.  I dunno about scm manager, but vanilla Mercurial will not try to use pushkey w/ a server that doesn't support it -- it auto-detects capabilities such that you don't need to worry about server/client version differences.