# Hg Push: does not appear to be an hg repository

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12493768/4746087) question, I have problems pushing to a Mercurial repository. In my case, pushing is just not possible, while everything else works. The error log:

```
hg push http://myrepo/hg/repo
pushing to http://myrepo/hg/repo
searching for changes
'http://myrepo/hg/repo' does not appear to be an hg repository:
```

The push is not executed, nor are any hooks installed. No network errors. Everything else works fine. (clone, pull, incoming, outgoing...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the repository got stuck in a certain state, not allowing pushes. Running the following command on the remote repository fixed the issue:

```
hg recover
```